# Generate ICollection in Visual Studio Class Digaram

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to model My Entities , the problem is visual studio generate IEnumerable in collection properties .

IEnumerable doesn't work with EF , i need to create ICollection.

i believe changing I Enumerable manually in generated code is not right workflow .

how can i make visual studio create ICollection instead of IEnumerable ?

thanks

Comment: you have aslo posted the answer just change the generated code manually ICollection<T>  inhertied from IEnumerable<T>

Comment: i want it automatic

Comment: then please more explaining: you are using Code First? Explain please how are you generting the classes/entities from the class diagram? it is not clear for me why you are doing that?